# Python multiprocessing working slower when using more cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

So, i've been using Starmap from the pathos Multiprocessing fork, trying to solve pyomo instances in parallel. The code works in my computer without any problems. Thing is, im trying to run the same code in a computer with 5 times as many cpu cores (mine has 4, the other one has 20), but the code becomes twice as slow (at least by wallclock time).

The parallelized part of the code goes something like this:

```
def foo(model, data, sc):
  inst = model.create_instance(data[sc])
  opt = SolverFactory(solver)
  results = opt.solve(inst)


def pool_foo(model, data, scenarios):

  args_list = [i for i in range(scenarios)]

  with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    for sc in range(scenarios):
      args_list[sc] = (model, data, sc)
    results_list = pool.starmap(foo, args_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

  print("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  model_definition
  data_definition
  pool_foo(model, data, 50)
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening / how to solve this? Any help is appreciated!

My computer specs:

- Windows 8.1
- Intel Core i3-2348M CPU @2.30 Ghz 2.30 Ghz (2 cores each)
- 6 GB RAM

The other computer's specs

- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
- Intel Xeon Silver 4114 CPU @2.20 GHz 2.19 GHz (10 cores each)
- 64 GB RAM

Comment: Depends on the details of the algorithm being run. If it costs more to move the data between processes than it costs to actually run the algorithm on a single process, then `multiprocessing` is a losing game.

Comment: (Honestly, I wouldn't choose Python for something where performance matters in the first place -- `multiprocessing` is a hack to fight against the GIL; better to choose a language that doesn't have a GIL at all).

Comment: I observed that scipy solvers partly already utilise parallel computing. Trying to run one solver on each core will not bring any benefit, but you'll pay the cost of data transfer. What if you try on `cpu_count() // 2` processors or even less? Same picture?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy serial solving was still slower than the parallelization, but the change in performance from each computer was the part i couldn't understand

Comment: @Dr.V you were right! I changed the cpu_count to 2, then 4. Solving time went down to a third! I'm gonna keep iterating to find the lowest i can get, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you make number of processes be equal to the number of cores, you're paying for more data transfer between processes (which is expensive!) on a machine with more cores; simple as that.

Comment: I'm the pathos `author`. You should note that `pathos` pools are not destroyed with `close; join`.  They stick around in memory, and can then either `restart` or `clear`.  That gains some speed, but if you are creating a lot of pools, and not reallocating the memory, then you can slow down your processing.  Probably not what is happening, but just FYI.